# How to I specify the middle point when using background_gradient on a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, gradient, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format a dataframe in python by applying a background gradient (classic red to blue) formatting to multiple columns at the same time. I need the gradient to be done with respect to  the whole set of columns and have 0 as middle point (so background color for 0 should be white) and ideally the lowest negative number as dark red and highest positive number as dark blue). I am also looking to make the font white for all the "0" cells so that they would look like empty white cells

I tried to apply the background_gradient to the list of columns enforcing the low and high (for some reason vmin and vmax do not work).

```
df.style.hide_index().\
    format('{:.2%}',subset = pct_cols).\
    format('{:.1%}',subset = mv_cols).\
    background_gradient(subset = tcav_cols, axis=None,cmap="RdBu", low = -0.5, high = 0.5)
```

However the 0 cells are still pinkish rather than white and I haven't managed to find a way to set the font white without writing a separate line for each column (as I need the condition x = 0 to apply to every cell, independently from what happens in the rest of the row or column). In this way I m also not making the highest number dark blue as I am hardcoding the max and min values.

See below example with data:

```
data = [[-0.5,-0.1],[0.3,-0.9],[0.2,-0.02],[0.15,-0.3],[0,0.001]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B'])

df.style.hide_index().\
    format('{:.1%}',subset =  ['A','B']).\
    background_gradient(subset =  ['A','B'], axis=None,cmap="RdBu", low = -0.5, high = 0.5)
```

Comment: Can you provide some data of your df?

Comment: I added now a sample data-frame with random data (same behavior)